# Xcode says app is running, but cannot find app on my iOS 14 device

Tags: swift, react-native, react-native-ios, ios14, xcode12

Everything was working fine before upgrading to Xcode 12 and iOS14. Now when I run the debug build on my device, Xcode says that the app is running, but the app is nowhere to be found on my device.

In the app library, I can see the name of my development team as a category and it's empty. And for some reason, I am able to find the app inside of Settings through search. However, I am unable to launch the app.

Thanks in advance.